# Pushing view controller within viewDidAppear doesn't work

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

## Steps to Reproduce

**1)** Create a navigation controller and 3 view controllers.

**firstViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"DEBUG: first screen did appear");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondScreen"] animated:NO];
}
```

**secondViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"DEBUG: second screen did appear");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdScreen"] animated:YES];
}
```

**thirdViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"DEBUG: third screen did appear");
}
```

**2)** make `firstViewController` (aka firstScreen in storyboard) the root view controller of the navigation controller.

**3)** Run app and notice that the navigation bar has updated to show the third screen's title, but still shows the second screen's content.

## Notes

I've tried using `UINavigationControllerDelegate`'s `-( void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` method since it seems to fire after the `viewDidAppear` method, but it didn't fix the issue.

I also tried manually setting the navigation controller's `viewControllers` thinking it would skip some "this view controller is active" logic and allow the problematic push to work, but it didn't.

## Solution

The only solution I could come up with was using a delayed call to push the desired view controller in **secondViewController.m**:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 250 * USEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdScreen"] animated:YES];
});
```

## Problem

I'd like to understand why this is not working as expected. Based on some other SO answers I've seen on semi-relevant questions, it may have something to do with a run loop, but I can't confirm or deny that (seems possible since dispatching the push allows it to work).

Can anyone else with more knowledge/experience enlighten me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I'm pretty confident that if you were to set `animated:YES` when pushing the second view controller in **firstViewController.m**, the *final* UI state would look as expected, with the third screen's content and title both correctly visible.

However, this is clearly not the transition effect you're aiming for. And why does the `animated` flag make an iota of difference anyway?

If you set a break point in `-viewDidAppear:` and look at the stack traces both for the case where `animated == YES` and `animated == NO`, it looks to me like when `animated == NO`, `-viewDidAppear:` is invoked during a view layout operation in the `UINavigationController`. My money's on this being the reason that you're final view looks incorrect; performing a push now would be doing so before the previous push has completely finished.

This is where run loop considerations come in. We want the `UINavigationController`'s view layout (which is happening on the main run loop's current loop cycle) to finish before asking for the next push. A simple way to achieve that is to queue the push to happen on the *next* cycle of the main run loop. A delay will certainly do the trick (I believe a delay of `0` is enough to delay to the next run loop cycle, so you could try replacing `250 * USEC_PER_SEC` with `0`). Another way would be to dispatch the action onto the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdScreen"] animated:YES];
});
```

So my answer is kind of speculative, but based on some evidence. It feels slightly unsatisfactory that, when performing `UINavigationController` transitions, `-viewDidAppear:` only indicates the true end of the transition when it's animated, however that does seem to be the case.

Comment: I lean toward your claims being true. In retrospect, I'm sure it was something to do with transition timing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this doesn't work exactly, probably has to do with timing. But for pushing multiple view controllers onto a navigation controller, the preferred method is to use `setViewControllers:animated:`

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[navigationController viewControllers]];
[viewControllers addObjectsFromArray:viewControllersToPush];
[navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

Comment: I already tried that as mentioned in the notes section of my question.  It didn't help because I can't do it all in one call. The second view controller pushes the third view controller conditionally. Thanks for sharing though.