# Pushing viewController from viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I am trying to push a `UIViewController` (Called A) from `viewWillAppear` OR `viewDidAppear` of `ViewController` (Called B). Which is working fine.

But when I am popping A... B doesn't push it(A) again (Or I can say It is not showing its view) ... But when I am trying same after disable AutoLayout for my `Storyboard`, It is pushing A again after popping.

I have 3 solutions to resolve this issue... But I don't know why this is happening. Any one please update me about this issue. Thanks in advance.

**When Auto Layout is enabled:**

```
                      (ViewDidAppear)   
rootViewController —————————————————————> demoViewController
                    (Push: animation:NO)


                       (Button Press)   
demoViewController —————————————————————> rootViewController
                    (Pop: animation:NO)
```

*As per code, rootViewController will push again demoViewController, But it is not showing demoViewController and navigationController is having demoViewController in its stack.*

**When Auto Layout is disabled:**

*Everything is working as we are assuming.*

Comment: Ok, You should probably never use viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear to push a viewController. Because after You would press "back" button, it would pop back (in case of viewDidAppear) and at once push the same viewController again (or in case ViewWillAppear - it could corrupt navigationController viewController stack, because it would push viewController, while trying to popping a viewController)

Comment: actually I have put some conditions over there... But I have solutions for that also... But I want reason.. because
It is working when autolayout is disabled

Comment: Could be some animations conflicts. You dismiss and push at the same time, which could cause animations to crash.
Try to add a small delay (like 0.1 secs) in the viewDidAppear before pushing. If it works then I was right.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer given in this question: [Pushing view controller within viewDidAppear doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417003/pushing-view-controller-within-viewdidappear-doesnt-work)

In my situation what you are describing was happening with auto layout disabled. This helped

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 250 * USEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myScreen"] animated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what view (and of what size) you have defined in the IB or in your code. Developers must have the through knowledge about using the AutoLayout feature in IB otherwise it leads to very nasty (unanticipated) bugs in the code.

So, i strongly recommend to go through this AutoLayout Guide: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1) I guess the contraints in views of viewcontroller A is giving the bug.

More precisely go to this page: [Working with Constraints in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH8-SW1)

So, without trying couldbe or shouldbe be clear from this link.

Answer (score 0):

You musn't push a `view Controller` into another in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`. Because after you have to set variables when you want to come back...

Have you set constraints in your `storyboard` ? Because it can become from it.

Comment: I have not added any constraints in storyboard... it is blank as default.