# pushViewController in viewWillAppear failed after popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

there have 3 view controllers, A,B,C, all designed in storyboard.

in all `pushViewController:` controllers were got from `[self.navigationController instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A/B/C_Controller"]`;

In A_ViewController ( root controller ):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:B_Controller animated:YES];
}
```

In B_ViewController:

```
-(IBAction)someButtonClick
{
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:C_Controller animated:YES];
}
```

In C_ViewController:

```
-(IBAction)someButtonClick
{
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**Problem:**
A_viewController -> B_viewController -> C_viewController is fine.

but after popToRootViewController to A From C, A can't push to B anymore.
and other `pushViewController:` all can't works, `popViewControllerAnimated:` also cause crash.

**Note.**

have tried

```
// in A view
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:B_viewController animated:YES];
 })
```

in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417003/pushing-view-controller-within-viewdidappear-doesnt-work), but it doesn't works for me.

does anyone know what happens in view controller stacks?

have struggling in this issue all day, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly did you try from the referenced question ? The only suspicious part of your code is `animated` argument at `viewWillAppear`, are you actually aiming for some kind of stacked animations ?

Comment: just edit the question, sorry for the confusion, my bad

Comment: Please describe what you aim to achieve, then we might be able to guide you.

Comment: Interestingly, I can't reproduce it, might be the differences at the code as there're some strange parts like missing argument at `viewWillAppear` and using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` on `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you When you `popToViewController` from C, the `viewWillAppear` method will in A be called just before the animation. Now, at this point, since the transition is in progress, you might get some kind of warning in the debugger like:

```
"Warning: Attempting to push .... while a transition is in progress"
```

You need to call the navigation controller methods in such a way that they do not overlap each other.

Calling `pushViewController` in the `viewDidAppear` method of A would be better in this context.